# Get Elememnt By Class Does'not Work in Requests_html

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

everyone I am trying to get data from an website which is called 'biletix.com'. I have tried to solve the problem that I am facing. I have look at the docs and stackoverflow questions but still I dont get any data. Why is it not working?

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession


session2 = HTMLSession()

rghtml = session2.get('https://www.biletix.com/etkinlik-grup/382508946/TURKIYE/tr')

rghtml.html.render(sleep=1, keep_page=True, scrolldown=1)
results = rghtml.html.find('.current-text ng-tns-c186-9')

print(results)


print('ok')
```

This is what I get as output:

```
[]
ok
```

What I expect is I want to get the data of given class of '.current-text ng-tns-c186-9'

Answer (score 1):

Your current selector is looking for a node with the name `ng-tns-c186-9` under a node that has a class `current-text`.

The CSS selector for a node with the two classnames `current-text` and `ng-tns-c186-9` would be `.current-text.ng-tns-c186-9`, so try

```
results = rghtml.html.find('.current-text.ng-tns-c186-9')
```

instead.

Comment: Still doesnt work...